# @DELETE in Restful Web Services

Tags: rest

When i am using @delete I am string is passing as null. Help me out with this thanks in advance !

```
    @Path("/database")

    public class Controller {

    DataResource datar = new DataResource();

    @DELETE

    @Path("/delemp/{id}")

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response delete(@PathVariable("id")  String id) {

            System.out.println("delete"+ id);

        String status="";

        status = datar.delete(Integer.parseInt(id));

       return Response.ok(status).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*").entity("Emp is deleted").build();
    }
}
```

// Implementation

```
public String delete(int id) {

    System.out.println(sql);
    int result = 0;
    try {
        con = db.get_Connection();
        sql =" delete from emp99 where id =?" ;
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);  
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,id);
        result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        preparedStatement.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    if(result > 0) 
        return "Success"; 
        else
            return "Failed"; 
}
```

Output:

It is taking as null

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8008"]
Dec 13, 2017 3:18:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13391 ms
delete

Comment: A title is made to ask the question ... If it is to describe a problem we use the description ... It is not only there to put code ...

Comment: Why would you revert an edit that actually made the question readable although still not really understandable? What is the problem and how have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the majority annotations in your code it is obvious that you are using a JAX-RS implementation possibly Jersey.

JAX-RS doesn't have a `@PathVariable("id")` it has a `@PathParam("id")` so use that.

Comment: i tried by using @PathParam also but it is taking the id as null